# How can I stopPropagation when angular mat-select option selected?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, stoppropagation

I want to stopPropagation when angular material select changes, Seems like the returned $event doesn't have the stopPropagation()?

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="handleSelectionChange($event)">
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the mat-select with a div. That can be used to capture and stop the same click event that triggers the mat-select selection.

```
<div (click)="prevent($event)">
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="handleSelectionChange()">
  </mat-select>
<div>

prevent($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the (valueChange) event. Then use $event.stopPropagation() inside the change handler

```
<mat-select (valueChange)="handleSelectionChange($event)">
</mat-select>
```

Comment: It gives `TypeError: $event.stopPropagation is not a function` bro as only the selected id is returned